# using several <script> tags doesn't work - only one script is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using lazy-load google maps js plugin on my webpage and now I wanted to add a popup using another java script. In my code so far it looked like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.lazy-load-google-maps.js"></script>
```

and lazy load works, however when I put right after that the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script>
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  alignTop: true,
  overflowY: 'scroll'
});
</script>
```

Then the popup shows up when I click the link, but lazy load doesn't... What can be the issue?

==================
edit:
User Adaneo was right, shame on me, I added the jquery library twice :(
First one on top from my custom js's and later on from:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: And you didn't by any chance add the jQuery script twice, did you ?

Comment: Is the third script before the actual `ajax-popup-link` in your html? If so you'll need to surround that with a `$(function(){ .. })` or `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })` - otherwise the selector will select nothing because the document hasn't finished loading when that script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting untill the dom is loaded

```
    <script>
$(function(){
   $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
     type: 'ajax',
     alignTop: true,
     overflowY: 'scroll'
   });
});
</script>
```